# wenzhixin bootstrap table does load any of the data that's passed to the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table

I'm wrestling with this table. Data is returned to the page in what seems to be the correct format, but nothing is displayed except for a gray bar.

This is my table

```
<table id="contactHistoryList"
   data-toggle="table"
   data-url="/api/members/@ViewBag.MemberID/contact-history">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td data-field="id">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ID)</td>
        <td data-field="contactedOn">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ContactedOn)</td>
        <td data-field="method">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Method)</td>
        <td data-field="reason">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Reason)</td>
        <td data-field="direction">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Direction)</td>
        <td data-field="outcome">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Outcome)</td>
        <td data-field="notes">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Notes)</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The url goes out to my api controller

```
[Route("{memberId:int:min(1)}/contact-history")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetContactHistory(int memberId)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<MemberContactView> contactHistory = await _memberContactRepository.GetByMemberIdAsViewAsync(memberId);

            var results = contactHistory
                .OrderByDescending(ch => ch.CreatedOn)
                .Select(ch => new MemberContactHistoryItem
                {
                    ID = ch.ID,
                    ContactedOn = ch.ContactedOn,
                    Method = ch.ContactMethod,
                    Reason = ch.ContactReason,
                    Direction = ch.InboundContact,
                    Outcome = ch.ContactDisposition,
                    Notes = ch.Notes
                });

            //_logger.Debug("Returning OK (200).");
            return Ok(results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // _logger.Error("Returning Internal Server Error (500).", ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

The results are return to the page: //localhost:52317/api/members/67636/contact-history?order=asc

```
0: {id: 35167, contactedOn: "2015-04-17T18:40:00", method: "Home Phone", reason: "Confirmation",…}

[
  {
    "id": 35167,
    "contactedOn": "2015-04-17T18:40:00",
    "method": "Home Phone",
    "reason": "Confirmation",
    "direction": false,
    "outcome": "Left Voice Message",
    "notes": "Left VM."
  }
]
```

The page loads and all I see is a grey bar: localhost:52317/CallCenter/Campaigns/14/Solicit/67636

[image]

Why is does the page not load any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table's headers I have as `<td>`. They should be `<th>`.